# openstack compute service list --service nova-compute return null line after install nova

Tags: openstack

I'am install openstack step by step,when I finish install nova followed by the official install doc https://docs.openstack.org/nova/queens/install/compute-install-ubuntu.html

I use command: 
openstack compute service list --service nova-compute

but get a null line

can someone help me?Thanks